# Web2py, switch custom widget from input type=text to textarea

Tags: web2py

I have a web2py database definition which used to be Field('my text', type="text"), but which I have switched to type='string', length=40, so that I can index it properly on the database side.

In a view generated by web2py, I then do

```
{{=form.custom.widget.my_text}}
```

But this has now switched from a <textarea> field to an <input type="text"> field. Is there any way I can force the widget to go back to the textarea type, so that I can get an input that text wraps, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each field type gets a default form widget, but you can override that when defining the field:

```
Field('my_text', widget=SQLFORM.widgets.text.widget)
```

For more details, see the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Widgets).